# Returning Enumeration Values From A Method

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a simple shotgun game where the user vs the CPU and the both pick shot, shield or reload but In my GetOptionFromUser method I am not sure how to return value from the enumeration method depending on what the user chose.

Any Guidance would be appreciated
Here is my methods

```
enum ShotgunOption
         {
             Shoot = 1,
             Reload = 2,
             Shield = 3


         }
        static void DisplayMenu()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please pick an item:");
            Console.WriteLine("S - Shoot");
            Console.WriteLine("P - Shield");
            Console.WriteLine("R - Reload");         
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");

        }

        static ShotgunOption GetOptionFromUser()
        {
            char menuItem;
            DisplayMenu();
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select A Option");
            menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            while (menuItem != 'S' && menuItem != 'P' &&
                menuItem != 'R' && menuItem != 'X')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error - Invalid menu item");
                DisplayMenu();
                menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            return ShotgunOption;
        }
        static void DisplayResults(ShotgunOption UserOption,ShotgunOption CPUOption, int UserScore, int UserBullets, int CPUBullets)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Giving up?");
        Console.WriteLine("You Chose {0}, The Computer Chose{1} Your Score is {3} . You had {4} Bullet(s). The CPU had {5} bullets(s).", UserOption, CPUOption, UserScore, UserBullets, CPUBullets);
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a switch statement (or a series of if statements) to return an explicit enum value that depends on the selected menu value. Like this:

```
    static ShotgunOption GetOptionFromUser()
    {
        char menuItem;
        DisplayMenu();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Select A Option");
        menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        while(true)
        {
            switch(menuItem)
            {
                case 'S': return ShotgunOption.Shoot;
                case 'P': return ShotgunOption.Shield;
                case 'R': return ShotgunOption.Reload;
                case 'X': return ShotgunOption.Exit;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error - Invalid menu item");
                    DisplayMenu();
                    menuItem = char.ToUpper(char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
        }

        return ShotgunOption.Exit; // to keep compiler happy
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the method GetOptionFromUser you need to check what the user has selected. Based on that, you return ShotgunOption.Shot, ShotgunOption.Reload or ShotgunOption.Shield. Something like this:

```
if (menuItem == 'S')
     return ShotgunOption.Shoot;
if (menuItem == 'P')
     return ShotgunOption.Shield;
```

...

Apart from this, take this into account:

1) Separate the User Interface (UI) from the logic of the application. In the UI layer you should only check user input, validate and pass the good requests to the business layer. Business layer will do the work and return results to UI layer.

2) Don't use "static" all the time. Static only makes sense when you don't need an object or when you want to share values among objects of the same time or when the class only has methods that don't depend on the state of the object.

Comment: or: use a switch statement instead

Comment: Second on the static - while private static methods are fine, public static methods should be used sparingly

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of the fact that a char in itself can be treated as a number, and that those numbers can be assigned directly to an enumeration:

```
  enum ShotgunOption
        {
            Shoot = 'S',
            Reload = 'R',
            Shield = 'P'
        }
```

That way checking can be done by seeing if the value is defined. Using your char menuitem as an example:

```
 // char menuitem...
 //X should be checked before and handled appropiately, or else added in the enumeration
 if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ShotgunOption), (int)menuItem ))
            return (ShotgunOption)menuItem ;
 //throw exception, return nullable<shotgunoption> or print error message.
```

Having mentioned that, just some food for thought: if, instead of an enumeration, you define a class which holds the menukey, the description as well as the action, you can use a list of that class for displaying the menu, determining the chosen action *and* performing that action by implementing it in the class itself.